# website crashes in IE, possibly a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, internet-explorer, memory, memory-leaks

A website I'm working on crashes in IE8 through 10. I have been trying to determine if it is related to a memory leak, but the tools available for IE are not really great. I've tried using Sieve ... as well as dynaTrace ... Sieve reports no memory leak, but does report on multiple orphaned dom nodes. dynaTrace does not support memory analysis in IE, and the issue does not seem to present itself in Firefox.

I've reviewed heap snapshots in Chrome Dev Tools... and garbage collection seems to be fine there after about 10 seconds or so of the site loading.

Here is the site in question: http://midlandsbiz.whosonthemove.com/

After several minutes on the site in IE, my AVG will pop-up saying that it is consuming too much memory. This is also evidenced by my fan whirring on my laptop, and the ultimate crash of the site.

This happens on multiple computers, on different networks, using different versions of IE.

I was also able to replicate the issue using the WP theme author's site:

http://kopatheme.com/demo/passion/

I'm getting no response / support at all from the WP theme author about this issue.

I was hoping that someone had some ideas on what might be causing this... or could point me in a direction for some tools that I can use to profile javascript memory usage in IE?

Answer (score 3):

You have some major memory leaks and a HUGE memory footprint. There are actually great memory profiling tools in IE, just open F12 and choose the memory profiling tool. You will want to start a profile. When you take a snapshot you will get a simple visual telling you the size of the page in memory and how many objects. When you have a memory leak you will see a blue circle with the number of leaks. Clicking on that will take you to a view of the objects and you can swim through the tree to find the source of your issues.

I can also tell you have many fundamental performance issues in the site. You have over 200 HTTP requests and 4MB of content. You also have many 404s.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: here is your webpagetest profile http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140628_S1_EH2/